# syntax error, unexpected '$records1' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I get the following error "syntax error, unexpected '$records1' (T_VARIABLE)" if I put the if line in my code. Why? I don't understand it.

```
<?php

$continent = $_GET['continent'];
if (!empty($continent)
{

    $records1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name, capital From country where continent='$continent'");


    while ($data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($records1))
    {
        $nume=$data1['name'];
        $capitala=$data1['capital'];
        echo '<br>'.'<br>';
        echo 'Tara'.' '.$nume.' are capitala '.$capitala.'.';
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if has a missing parentheses, it's not supposed to be

```
if (!empty($continent)
```

it's

```
if (!empty($continent))
```